# How can I get a copy of the volume data onto a folder on my desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For example, say if my containers got deleted, and the rm - v removes the volumes , I want to be able to store the volume data locally on my machine. So that in future, if I were to create a new container(s) I would like to use this same volume data. In other words, I want to map a volume to a WP content and spin it back up when it is started.

```
version: '3.3'

    services:
       db:
         image: mysql:5.7
         volumes:
           - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
         restart: always
         environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
           MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
           MYSQL_USER: wordpress
           MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

       wordpress:
         depends_on:
           - db
         image: wordpress:latest
         ports:
           - "8000:80"
         restart: always
         environment:
           WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
           WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
           WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
           WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
        db_data: {}
```

Comment: docker volumes are stored in /var/lib/docker/volumes, is just that they are managed by docker. Ref. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes for an example of how to backup and restore volumes. It may be tempting to bind mount a local directory however not ideal imo as you’re coupling the deployment to the host (wouldn’t work in i.e. k8s where the pod can be scheduled on any given node in your cluster).

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
   db:
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    db_data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        o: bind
        type: none
        device: /disk1/myfolder-data
```

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver) for details